# Simple web general localization/translation backend (using mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, localization, translation

Hi is there a free avaible translation backend with database avaible which can handle multiple users(no login needed), multiple languages (UTF-8) and provides automatic google translation?

I just need this tool to fill a database (preferable mysql) with simple tables like this:

language | label | text

english | _helloworld | Hello World!
german | _helloworld | Hallo Welt!

I don't care about export since this will have to be created anyways..

Thanks it would be a real timesaver if something with an usable UI exists already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: (not exactly what I was looking for but fits in)

http://webtranslateit.com